# Badge notifications for Teams do not clear after clicking on them

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, achievements-dialog

On August 1, that is, 5 days ago, I earned the Nice Answer and Enlightened badge in a Team.

However, no matter how many times I click on it, it keeps showing with a blue background reserved for "new stuff".

So if I click on the badge icon and scroll down a bit it starts with something like this:

> [image]

and after a lot of scrolling down, this one shows:

> [image]

Comment: I pinged Tim Post about this in the Tavern: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6819439#6819439 He was going to forward it: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6819687#6819687 but that was a couple of months ago ...

Comment: at the end, what kind of things we can take from a hotel? I am curious :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif [plenty of them!](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/39715/6997) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this up. I know this has taken a while but I finally got a fix out for this issue.

When you're looking at your achievements, we're setting a `ViewedDate` on all achievements so they won't be highlighted the next time you're opening the list of achievements.

For Teams, we failed to update that `ViewedDate` properly. I fixed that. If you take a look now, your Teams' achievements should be properly marked as read and won't bug you anymore.